# How to change date format to dd-MM-yyyy for simplecursoradapter list view using cursor query

Tags: java, android, sqlite

For my list view using simple cursor adapter I want to display the date as dd-MM-yyyy. In my table I store date as yyyy-MM-dd in TX_DATE column. How to make it out in the following code:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
String[] columns = {VivzHelper.UID, helper.TX_NAME,
"SUM("+helper.TX_AMOUNT+") AS "+helper.TX_AMOUNT,
helper.TX_DATE};

Cursor c = db.query(VivzHelper.TX_TABLE, columns, helper.TX_ID + "='" +             
name + "' AND " + helper.TX_DATE + " BETWEEN '"
+ datefrom.from_date + "' AND '"  + dateto.to_date + "  ' 
",null,helper.TX_NAME, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the following code(date format I have changed as per your need) as per your requirement to get the date in the format you need:

```
String givenDateString = dateTime;// dateTime variable is the variable in which you are storing the date currently
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+0530"));
            try {
                Date mDate = sdf.parse(givenDateString);
                timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually the date in table is like '2015-04-24' and the same thing is displayed in list view. But I want it to be displayed as '24-05-2014' is list view.

Comment: You do not need timeInMilliseconds line mDate value will be the date in your required format

Comment: You can change the format using the above code and then insert it in to the database. That will be better.

Comment: If I change the format like dd-MM-yyyy for insertion I get problem while selecting rows for a date range using column TX_DATE. Only yyyy-MM-dd is selecting rows properly using BETWEEN clause .

Comment: ok. When you fetch data from database, take this particular column and format the date as shown above and add it to list view.

Comment: I used your code like this before list view statement, but get exception at line ' SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY", Locale.ENGLISH);'
Logcat exception as follows:
 Unknown pattern character 'Y'

Comment: sorry its not capital Y its lowercase y

Comment: Check the edited answer. Please let me know if you have get error.

Comment: Yes that Y error has gone but I get date result in list view unchanged as 
'yyyy-MM-dd'. You said at the time of fetching the column 'TX_DATE' from 
table we should change the format to 'dd-MM-yyyy'. How to do it in the code I posted above under my question:
String[] columns = {VivzHelper.UID, helper.TX_NAME,
"SUM("+helper.TX_AMOUNT+") AS "+helper.TX_AMOUNT,
helper.TX_DATE};

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76132/discussion-between-keshav1234-and-user3144078).